# Installing Avro in Mac OS X

Tags: python, osx-mountain-lion, avro

I was looking at Avro RPC for Python at https://github.com/phunt/avro-rpc-quickstart#python. Seems the package `libsnappy-dev` is available only in [Ubuntu/Debian](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libsnappy-dev). Is there a equivalent package for Mac OS X that can be installed via brew?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An equivalent of the Ubuntu libsnappy-dev package is simply snappy, you can install it like this:

```
brew install snappy
```

Optionally, you might need to add links to the libraries in /usr/local/lib so other packages can link to it:

```
 cd /usr/local/lib/
 ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/snappy/1.1.1/lib/libsnappy.1.dylib
 ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/snappy/1.1.1/lib/libsnappy.a
 ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/snappy/1.1.1/lib/libsnappy.dylib
```

Comment: This came up when searching for why qemu was looking for libsnappy on Mac OSX and not finding it. The above answer works as a solution.